# OOfflineClusterException Message: Cannot read a record from the offline cluster

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

If some record is available in an offline cluster and I try to fetch it using index, it gives OOfflineClusterException. Why should it access offline cluster, shouldn't it be normal record not found situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, I've just opened an [new issue](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/5423) for this, and fixed in v2.1.7-SNAPSHOT. v2.1.7 GA will be online in few hours.